# Recording audio from many source/microphones

Tags: android, iphone, ios, audio-recording, microphone

I'm curious if it's possible to record audio from many sources and if not, what's the limitation.

Many current devices have two internal microphones (basically for noise reduction). On top of that it's possible to plug additional external one using audiojack. You can as well have another audio stream via bluetooth headset.

You are allowed to specify AudioSource in android but is it possible to do recording from many sources at the same time? I'm also interested how the situation look like on the iOS devices.

Comment: I haven't implemented anything like this myself, but it seems that you can specify multiple input channels by using the `setAudioChannels` method in the Media Recorder class.. That being said, I don't know if there is a limit to how many channels you can use or if you can record from internal and external mics at the same time.

Comment: @Cbas so...where is the official android documentation for mobile hardware developers and the sound implementations?Everyone is asking but there is no booklets

Comment: See the docs page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html